# Sending Click with user32.dll, messages appear in spy++ but button isn't clicked

Tags: c#, dllimport, user32, spy++

I have problems with sending a Click to an application with the user32.dll. the button does not be clicked, but in spy++ the message do appear.
i'm using win7 x64

The code is written in c#:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string strClassName, string strWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string lpClassName, string lpWindowTitle);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint wCmd);

    //
    // Finds a window in the whole tree of childs for a parent window.
    //
    static IntPtr FindWindowRecursive(IntPtr hParent, string szClass, string szCaption)
    {
        IntPtr hResult = FindWindowEx(hParent, IntPtr.Zero, szClass, szCaption);
        if (hResult != IntPtr.Zero)
            return hResult; // found it

        // enumerate all childs and if found one that has childs go in
        IntPtr hChild = FindWindowEx(hParent, IntPtr.Zero, null, null); // first child
        if (hChild != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            // let's enumerate
            do
            {
                hResult = FindWindowRecursive(hChild, szClass, szCaption);
                if (hResult != IntPtr.Zero)
                    return hResult;  // found it
            } while ((hChild = GetWindow(hChild, GW_HWNDNEXT)) != IntPtr.Zero);
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero; // no childs, so no window was found
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntPtr win = FindWindow("Omnipage17_MainWnd_Class", "Unbenanntes OmniPage-Dokument 1 - OmniPage");
                SetForegroundWindow(win);
        ShowWindowAsync(win, SW_RESTORE);
        IntPtr ButtonHandle = FindWindowRecursive(win, "BarButton", "c");
        SetActiveWindow(win);
        //sEND Lbuttondown
        IntPtr ptr = SendMessage(ButtonHandle, 0x0201, new IntPtr(0x0001), MakeLParam(81,28));
        //Thread.Sleep(10);
        //Mousemove
        ptr = SendMessage(ButtonHandle, 0x0200, new IntPtr(0x0001), MakeLParam(86,24));
        //lbuttonup
        ptr = SendMessage(ButtonHandle, 0x0202, new IntPtr(0x0001), MakeLParam(81, 28));

        //SendMessage(ButtonHandle, BM_CLICK, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
```

Here are the messages of spy++ of that button:
[image]

If i send the the messages i get following: 
i don't if that is that problem but the lbuttondown, buttoup appears 2 times ( S + R ) and if i'm clicking it manuelly it gets 1 message (P) 
also tried to do it with WM_CLICK but then i have the same problem with it

*Edit: 
Using now PostMessage so spy++ shows the same messages as i click it manually, but still the button seems not to be clicked*

[image]

---

With this library I have the same problem.

code:

```
SetForegroundWindow(win);
Rectangle re;
GetWindowRect(ButtonHandle, out re);

Cursor.Position = new Point((re.X + re.Width)/2, (re.Y + re.Height)/2);
WindowsInput.InputSimulator.SimulateKeyDown(WindowsInput.VirtualKeyCode.LBUTTON);
WindowsInput.InputSimulator.SimulateKeyUp(WindowsInput.VirtualKeyCode.LBUTTON);
```

Message are sent, but button isn't be clicked
[image]

**Edit:**

thanks for that link (http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingLync2010SuperSimpleAutoAnswerVideoKioskWithFullScreen.aspx), but also with this library i have the same problem :/

code:

```
SetForegroundWindow(win);
Rectangle re;
GetWindowRect(ButtonHandle, out re);

Cursor.Position = new Point((re.X + re.Width)/2, (re.Y + re.Height)/2);
WindowsInput.InputSimulator.SimulateKeyDown(WindowsInput.VirtualKeyCode.LBUTTON);
WindowsInput.InputSimulator.SimulateKeyUp(WindowsInput.VirtualKeyCode.LBUTTON);
```

Message are sent, but button isn't be clicked
[image]

**Edit2:**

Answer of user was deleted, because i posted my comment as an answer:

> This is not an answer, this belongs in your question. It doesn't match
>   your code, clearly you are still posting BM_CLICK. Which is wrong, it
>   should be sent and you should either send BM_CLICK or post the mouse
>   messages. And you are looking at the wrong window, it is button's
>   parent that gets the BN_CLICK notification and acts on it. Having the
>   processs' keyboard state wrong would be a typical failure mode. – Hans
>   Passant 18 hours ago

Regarding to that, why should it be the parents windows? bcs in spy++ (screenshot below i serached for that button (Class: BarButton) and the handle i get from user32.dll is also the same as that one in spy++
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Scott Hanselman recent blogged with something similar to this http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingLync2010SuperSimpleAutoAnswerVideoKioskWithFullScreen.aspx